# How to a particular line from a page content with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on a task which is proven much difficult for me.. Take a look at the content attached, it contain an email inviting people to bid for a project..
My task is to get the (1) The Company name and it Logo (if Possible) (2) The exalt Dew  date of the project according to what is stated in the email (3) The Location of the Project which Project or Company.. I am to do this with JavaScript, i have no idea on what function to use as i have never done this before.. Please your contribution and idea is appreciated.. thanks in advance..
Edited:
To make you guys understand what i mean.. I have included a screenshot image of the page content.. As the picture shows..This is mostly how the email content will look..the email will come from many sources though. My task is To grab the (1) Dew Date (2) Company Name (3) Location from the content of the email.. I don't have any idea how to do this but i believe it is possible.. Thanks for your responses.. 
[image]

```html
    <div dir="auto"></div><br><div><div dir="ltr">---------- Forwarded message ---------<br>From: <strong dir="auto">R&amp;O Construction Brady Hill</strong> <span dir="ltr">&lt;<a href="mailto:email@com2.smartbidnet.com">email@com2.smartbidnet.com</a>&gt;</span><br>Date: Thu, Mar 28, 2019, 2:30 PM<br>Subject: Olympus Hills Retail Center Exterior Renovation, Salt Lake City Invitation<br>To:  &lt;<a href="mailto:email@lonepeakmasonry.com">email@lonepeakmasonry.com</a>&gt;<br></div><br><br><img src="https://secure.smartbidnet.com/External/RequestReadReceipt.aspx?sCommunicationId=650105303&amp;oimg=1x1pic.gif" height="1" width="1">
<div style="width:100%"><table style="FONT-SIZE:11px;FONT-FAMILY:Verdana" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
<tr><td align="left"><div align="center"><a href="https://secure.smartbidnet.com/Main/Login.aspx?cId=bp_650105303&amp;sPassportKey=AA8D9C40EFA9643F173D40DD3EC0E0C1DFE05F39&amp;sBidId=437879&amp;st=101&amp;e=1" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer"><img align="left" src="https://secure.smartbidnet.com/ImagesAtProject/Icons/ClickHereBids-US.gif" border="0" width="457" height="56">
</a></div>
</td></tr>
<tr><td><font style="FONT-SIZE:12px;FONT-FAMILY:Arial">
If this link does not work, please go toÂ <a href="https://secure.smartbidnet.com/LRCD?st=102" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">https://secure.smartbidnet.com/LRCD</a>Â and enter the access key:Â 61f1868937df162
</font></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="https://secure.smartbidnet.com/Main/Login.aspx?cId=bp_650105303&amp;sPassportKey=AA8D9C40EFA9643F173D40DD3EC0E0C1DFE05F39&amp;sBidId=437879&amp;iR=1&amp;st=103&amp;e=1" style="font-weight:bold;color:#ff6f02;font-size:12px" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">Yes, I&#39;ll Bid All Codes</a>
<font style="font-weight:bold;color:#ff6f02;font-size:12px"> |Â </font><a href="https://secure.smartbidnet.com/Main/Login.aspx?cId=bp_650105303&amp;sPassportKey=AA8D9C40EFA9643F173D40DD3EC0E0C1DFE05F39&amp;sBidId=437879&amp;iR=0&amp;st=104&amp;e=1" style="font-weight:bold;color:#ff6f02;font-size:12px" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">No, I Won&#39;t Bid this Job</a>
<font style="font-weight:bold;color:#ff6f02;font-size:12px"> |Â </font><a href="https://secure.smartbidnet.com/Main/Login.aspx?cId=bp_650105303&amp;sPassportKey=AA8D9C40EFA9643F173D40DD3EC0E0C1DFE05F39&amp;sBidId=437879&amp;st=105&amp;e=1" style="font-weight:bold;color:#ff6f02;font-size:12px" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">Click Here to View the Project</a>
</td></tr>
</table><br><br>
<font style="FONT-SIZE:11px;FONT-FAMILY:Verdana"><h1 style="text-align:left">
<span style="font-size:x-large">
<span style="font-size:large">
<span style="font-size:x-large">
<span style="font-size:x-small">
Lone Peak Masonry (Draper, UT)

<br>Attention: 
Dave
 
Smith
</span>
<br></span>
<span style="font-size:x-large">Â 
<br></span></span></span></h1>
<h1 style="text-align:center">
<span style="font-size:x-large">R&amp;O Construction
<br>Invites You To Bid With Us</span></h1>

<table style="width:544px;height:147px;text-align:center" border="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>

<td style="text-align:left"><address>
<span style="font-size:x-small">Corporate Office
<br>933 Wall Ave.
<br>Ogden, UT
<br>84404
<br>P) phone Number
<br>F) Phone Number
<br></span></address></td>

<td>

<p><img src="https://secure.smartbidnet.com/Files/System_1064/images/Blue%20Logo(1).png" width="148" height="132">
<br>
<br><a href="http://www.randoco.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
<span style="font-size:xx-small">www.randoco.com</span></a></p>
</td>

<td><address style="text-align:right">
<span style="font-size:x-small">
<br>
<br>1743 W Alexander Street
<br>Suite #100
<br>West Valley City, UT
<br>84119
<br>P) 801-532-0123
<br>
<br>Â Â 
<br></span></address></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table style="width:100%;text-align:center" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>

<td>Â </td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>

<p style="text-align:center">
<span style="font-size:x-large">
<strong>
Olympus Hills Retail Center Exterior Renovation, Salt Lake City
</strong></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>

<p style="text-align:center">
<span style="font-size:large">
3979 South Wasatch Blvd.  - Salt Lake City, UT 84124-
</span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>Â </td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>

<p style="text-align:center">
<span style="font-size:large">
<strong>BIDS ARE DUE: 
April 17, 2019 03:00 PM
 
(MT)
</strong></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table style="width:100%;height:67px;text-align:center" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>

<td>Â </td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>

<p style="text-align:center">
<span style="font-size:medium">

<div style="text-align:center">
<span style="font-family:times new roman,times,serif;font-size:14pt">Exterior FaÃ§ade and Hardscape Remodel of the Olympus Hills Retail Center.
<br>
<br>Contractors are encouraged to visit the site prior to submitting their bids.
<br>
<br>Please submit your proposal through SmartBid, by email to Brady Hill, Estimator, <a href="mailto:email@randoco.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">email@randoco.com</a> or by fax to our Ogden Office Number.
<br>
<br>Bid Documents are also available on our website @ <a href="http://www.randoco.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">www.randoco.com</a>.
<br>
<br>Thank you for bidding with R&amp;O Construction.
<br></span></div>
</span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>Â </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table style="width:783px;height:75px;text-align:center" border="0">
<tbody>

<tr style="text-align:center" valign="bottom">

<td>
<span style="font-size:medium">
<span style="text-decoration:underline">Contact:</span></span></td>

<td>Â </td>

<td>
<span style="font-size:medium">
<span style="text-decoration:underline">Email:</span></span></td>

<td>Â </td>

<td>
<span style="font-size:medium">
<span style="text-decoration:underline">Phone:</span></span></td>

<td>Â </td>

<td>
<span style="font-size:medium">
<span style="text-decoration:underline">Fax:</span></span></td>
</tr>

<tr style="text-align:center" valign="top">

<td>
<span style="font-size:medium">Brady Hill</span></td>

<td>Â </td>

<td>
<span style="font-size:medium"><a href="mailto: " target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">email@randoco.com</a></span></td>

<td>Â </td>

<td>
<span style="font-size:medium"> </span></td>

<td>Â </td>

<td>
<span style="font-size:medium"> </span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table style="width:783px;height:144px;text-align:center" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>

<td style="text-align:center" valign="bottom"><em>
<span style="font-size:xx-small">Â </span></em></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td style="text-align:center" valign="bottom"><em>
<span style="font-size:xx-small">Bidders must comply with all City and State Licensing.
<br>
<br>Our Ins. requirements are $1,000,000 per occurrence, $2,000,000 aggregate &amp; $1,000,000 umbrella
<br>Survey subcontractors must have errors and omissions ins. (professional liability ins.).
<br>
<br>R&amp;O Construction is an EEO/AA Employer
<br>
<br>Contracts exceeding $200,000 may be subject to a confidential finance review.</span></em></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table style="width:100%;text-align:center" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>

<td style="text-align:center" valign="top">
<span style="font-size:xx-small">Utah License #95-292934-5501 ~ Arizona License #079839 ~ Nevada License #0034039</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td style="text-align:center" valign="top">
<span style="font-size:xx-small">California License #604354 d.b.a. ROCON COMPANY</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td style="text-align:center" valign="top">
<span style="font-size:xx-small">Washington License #CC01 ROCONC #088RG ~ New Mexico License #031344 ~ Idaho License #10211-AA</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<hr>

<table style="width:100%;text-align:center" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>

<td>
<span style="font-size:xx-small">
<br>PLEASE LOGIN USING THE INFORMATION ABOVE TO ACCEPT/REJECT THE INVITE AND TO DOWNLOAD PLANS</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<h1 style="text-align:center">
<br>
<br></h1></font>
<br><br>Â </div><div style="clear:both"></div><div>To Unsubscribe from receiving invitations, please <a href="https://secure.smartbidnet.com/External/Unsubscribe.aspx?DId=650105303&amp;PId=11151969&amp;CType=1&amp;st=106&amp;e=1" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">Click Here</a>
</div>
Â <div style="clear:both"></div><div>This is an automated email communication so replies to this address will not be answered.</div>

<img src="http://com2.smartbidnet.com/wf/open?upn=Ec818zpKGhsa3nrt3hc9G59m8rgwdlc1vywQ5NYZFh29X36ieqFQbbB1eQ4xPOWO-2FgC4OOD8kd-2B-2FjPJlecZt-2F6M8KmhcoHSqllBh9WbhzHtcM0wkxmIaspKs48mcpqonKaeL-2FjDx2lOs-2FFp6tpGe-2FTMErp1bqHae6GZ3vPk9Qt6zoxRiAMslZiJ1ZtX8ev-2FeBx-2BbWGnB4K5FU0IPE5Rz16Ouuw-2BjY3wGKDr2cchCFa-2BWyuOpUG0ldWPRiFOoc3W2HvIibgrKx1tSQOhzPUYlmMDl-2BfADgOv49bGNy02o-2B11bejm7LLV1tulxKEwIntqlQIz3YExI5xqsuAKxnm4TW4uPfJrlmOT5HTwNWs8NonM-3D" width="1" height="1" border="0" style="height:1px!important;width:1px!important;border-width:0!important;margin-top:0!important;margin-bottom:0!important;margin-right:0!important;margin-left:0!important;padding-top:0!important;padding-bottom:0!important;padding-right:0!important;padding-left:0!important">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know in JavaScript, but if you can use PHP, you can make use of the HTML tags in the given text, and get the data in between the tags using `preg_match` function.

Comment: In its current state your question is unlikely to attract helpful answers. Please cut down your code to a well formatted minimal reproducible example and show what script you've already written and where it fails.

Comment: Please view [help/how-to] and [help/mcve]. There's lots of examples out there that can help you. I think this problem might be a bit to challenging for you at the moment based on your question, but if you want to go big or go home you can look up parsing HTML with javascript. There's plenty of resources as there's many ways to do it depending on how to tag is created. Looking at web scrapers will also give you some insight.

Comment: @DysphoricUnicorn.. Thanks Sir.. I have re edit my question and also attached an image to to make my question more clearer.. As for the script, I have not written any Script for this as i don't have any idea on how to do this with JavaScript..

Answer (score 0):

If you have single static html and not other pages and this is test for your skills, then you have 3 options:

1. Create parser or use existing one (there is for instance sax parser for html).
2. Use regex (Regular Expression) I know you should not parse html with regex but you don't want to parse it but just find some regular things inside a file. If you have content of the file in a string then you can use `string.match(/<SOME REGEX>/);` to extract the data.
3. You can also inject the html into page (using innerHTML and hide it) and use jQuery or `document.querySelector` (`querySelectorAll`). that accept CSS selector to find DOM node then you can use DOM functions to extract data like `getAttribute()` or `innerHTML` `innerText`.

And to get the string with file content you have 2 options based on environment

1. Browser - use ajax to fetch the file to have it in browser.
2. Node.js - use fs module to read a file (e.g. `fs.readFile`).

Comment: Thanks for your response.. But i don't think this would work how with what i want to archive.. I have attached the image of the content sample above in my question.. take a look at it and tell me if your answer can work and how... Remember i am not dealing with HTML code.. I am to deal with the Text(String) of the content

Answer (score 0):

With [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) and `querySelectorAll` came up with this solution, I wrote the solution in a way to add custom parsers as well. This may not be the exact solution but might give you some direction to proceed.

```js
const DataParser = (function DataParser() {
  function Parser(inputStr) {
    this.input = inputStr;
    // creates a fragemet
    this.fragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(inputStr);
  }

  Parser.prototype.parse = function(parsers) {
    parsers = typeof parsers === 'string' ? [parsers] : parsers;

    return parsers.reduce((output, parser) => {
      output[parser] = this[parser] && this[parser]();
      return output;
    }, {});
  };

  Parser.prototype.selector = function(selector) {
    // converts HTMLCollection to Array
    return [].slice.call(this.fragment.querySelectorAll(selector));
  };

  Parser.prototype.contains = function(selector, text) {
    // select elements containing particular text
    return this.selector(selector).filter((element) => {
      return RegExp(text).test(element.textContent);
    });
  };

  Parser.prototype.address = function() {
    return this.selector('address')
      .map(address => {
        return address.textContent
          // removes phone and fax contents
          .split(/\P\)/)[0].trim().replace(/\n/g, ', ');
      });
  };

  Parser.prototype.email = function() {
    return this.selector('a[href^="mailto:"]').map(a => a.textContent.trim());
  };

  Parser.prototype.image = function() {
    return this.selector('img').map(img => img.src);
  };

  return {
    create: (input) => new Parser(input),
    parse: (input, selectors) => (new Parser(input)).parse(selectors),
    add: function(name, parser) {
      Parser.prototype[name] = function(...args) {
        return parser.apply(this, [this, ...args]);
      };
    }
  };
})();

// custom parsers
DataParser.add('logo', (parserContext) => {
  return parserContext.image()
    .filter(img => img.toLowerCase().includes('logo'))[0];
});


DataParser.add('companyName', (parserContext) => {
  return parserContext.selector('h1')
    .map(el => {
      return el.textContent.trim().split('\n')[0];
    })[1];
});


DataParser.add('dueDate', (parserContext) => {
  return parserContext.contains('strong', 'BIDS ARE DUE:')
    .map(el => {
      const date = el.textContent.split(':')[1];
      return date && date.trim();
    })[0];
});




const input = `<div dir="auto"></div><br><div><div dir="ltr">---------- Forwarded message ---------<br>From: <strong dir="auto">R&amp;O Construction Brady Hill</strong> <span dir="ltr">&lt;<a href="mailto:email@com2.smartbidnet.com">email@com2.smartbidnet.com</a>&gt;</span><br>Date: Thu, Mar 28, 2019, 2:30 PM<br>Subject: Olympus Hills Retail Center Exterior Renovation, Salt Lake City Invitation<br>To:  &lt;<a href="mailto:email@lonepeakmasonry.com">email@lonepeakmasonry.com</a>&gt;<br></div><br><br><img src="https://secure.smartbidnet.com/External/RequestReadReceipt.aspx?sCommunicationId=650105303&amp;oimg=1x1pic.gif" height="1" width="1">
<div style="width:100%"><table style="FONT-SIZE:11px;FONT-FAMILY:Verdana" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
<tr><td align="left"><div align="center"><a href="https://secure.smartbidnet.com/Main/Login.aspx?cId=bp_650105303&amp;sPassportKey=AA8D9C40EFA9643F173D40DD3EC0E0C1DFE05F39&amp;sBidId=437879&amp;st=101&amp;e=1" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer"><img align="left" src="https://secure.smartbidnet.com/ImagesAtProject/Icons/ClickHereBids-US.gif" border="0" width="457" height="56">
</a></div>
</td></tr>
<tr><td><font style="FONT-SIZE:12px;FONT-FAMILY:Arial">
If this link does not work, please go toÂ <a href="https://secure.smartbidnet.com/LRCD?st=102" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">https://secure.smartbidnet.com/LRCD</a>Â and enter the access key:Â 61f1868937df162
</font></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="https://secure.smartbidnet.com/Main/Login.aspx?cId=bp_650105303&amp;sPassportKey=AA8D9C40EFA9643F173D40DD3EC0E0C1DFE05F39&amp;sBidId=437879&amp;iR=1&amp;st=103&amp;e=1" style="font-weight:bold;color:#ff6f02;font-size:12px" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">Yes, I&#39;ll Bid All Codes</a>
<font style="font-weight:bold;color:#ff6f02;font-size:12px"> |Â </font><a href="https://secure.smartbidnet.com/Main/Login.aspx?cId=bp_650105303&amp;sPassportKey=AA8D9C40EFA9643F173D40DD3EC0E0C1DFE05F39&amp;sBidId=437879&amp;iR=0&amp;st=104&amp;e=1" style="font-weight:bold;color:#ff6f02;font-size:12px" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">No, I Won&#39;t Bid this Job</a>
<font style="font-weight:bold;color:#ff6f02;font-size:12px"> |Â </font><a href="https://secure.smartbidnet.com/Main/Login.aspx?cId=bp_650105303&amp;sPassportKey=AA8D9C40EFA9643F173D40DD3EC0E0C1DFE05F39&amp;sBidId=437879&amp;st=105&amp;e=1" style="font-weight:bold;color:#ff6f02;font-size:12px" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">Click Here to View the Project</a>
</td></tr>
</table><br><br>
<font style="FONT-SIZE:11px;FONT-FAMILY:Verdana"><h1 style="text-align:left">
<span style="font-size:x-large">
<span style="font-size:large">
<span style="font-size:x-large">
<span style="font-size:x-small">
Lone Peak Masonry (Draper, UT)

<br>Attention: 
Dave
 
Smith
</span>
<br></span>
<span style="font-size:x-large">Â 
<br></span></span></span></h1>
<h1 style="text-align:center">
<span style="font-size:x-large">R&amp;O Construction
<br>Invites You To Bid With Us</span></h1>

<table style="width:544px;height:147px;text-align:center" border="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>

<td style="text-align:left"><address>
<span style="font-size:x-small">Corporate Office
<br>933 Wall Ave.
<br>Ogden, UT
<br>84404
<br>P) phone Number
<br>F) Phone Number
<br></span></address></td>

<td>

<p><img src="https://secure.smartbidnet.com/Files/System_1064/images/Blue%20Logo(1).png" width="148" height="132">
<br>
<br><a href="http://www.randoco.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
<span style="font-size:xx-small">www.randoco.com</span></a></p>
</td>

<td><address style="text-align:right">
<span style="font-size:x-small">
<br>
<br>1743 W Alexander Street
<br>Suite #100
<br>West Valley City, UT
<br>84119
<br>P) 801-532-0123
<br>
<br>Â Â 
<br></span></address></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table style="width:100%;text-align:center" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>

<td>Â </td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>

<p style="text-align:center">
<span style="font-size:x-large">
<strong>
Olympus Hills Retail Center Exterior Renovation, Salt Lake City
</strong></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>

<p style="text-align:center">
<span style="font-size:large">
3979 South Wasatch Blvd.  - Salt Lake City, UT 84124-
</span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>Â </td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>

<p style="text-align:center">
<span style="font-size:large">
<strong>BIDS ARE DUE: 
April 17, 2019 03:00 PM
 
(MT)
</strong></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table style="width:100%;height:67px;text-align:center" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>

<td>Â </td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>

<p style="text-align:center">
<span style="font-size:medium">

<div style="text-align:center">
<span style="font-family:times new roman,times,serif;font-size:14pt">Exterior FaÃ§ade and Hardscape Remodel of the Olympus Hills Retail Center.
<br>
<br>Contractors are encouraged to visit the site prior to submitting their bids.
<br>
<br>Please submit your proposal through SmartBid, by email to Brady Hill, Estimator, <a href="mailto:email@randoco.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">email@randoco.com</a> or by fax to our Ogden Office Number.
<br>
<br>Bid Documents are also available on our website @ <a href="http://www.randoco.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">www.randoco.com</a>.
<br>
<br>Thank you for bidding with R&amp;O Construction.
<br></span></div>
</span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>Â </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table style="width:783px;height:75px;text-align:center" border="0">
<tbody>

<tr style="text-align:center" valign="bottom">

<td>
<span style="font-size:medium">
<span style="text-decoration:underline">Contact:</span></span></td>

<td>Â </td>

<td>
<span style="font-size:medium">
<span style="text-decoration:underline">Email:</span></span></td>

<td>Â </td>

<td>
<span style="font-size:medium">
<span style="text-decoration:underline">Phone:</span></span></td>

<td>Â </td>

<td>
<span style="font-size:medium">
<span style="text-decoration:underline">Fax:</span></span></td>
</tr>

<tr style="text-align:center" valign="top">

<td>
<span style="font-size:medium">Brady Hill</span></td>

<td>Â </td>

<td>
<span style="font-size:medium"><a href="mailto: " target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">email@randoco.com</a></span></td>

<td>Â </td>

<td>
<span style="font-size:medium"> </span></td>

<td>Â </td>

<td>
<span style="font-size:medium"> </span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table style="width:783px;height:144px;text-align:center" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>

<td style="text-align:center" valign="bottom"><em>
<span style="font-size:xx-small">Â </span></em></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td style="text-align:center" valign="bottom"><em>
<span style="font-size:xx-small">Bidders must comply with all City and State Licensing.
<br>
<br>Our Ins. requirements are $1,000,000 per occurrence, $2,000,000 aggregate &amp; $1,000,000 umbrella
<br>Survey subcontractors must have errors and omissions ins. (professional liability ins.).
<br>
<br>R&amp;O Construction is an EEO/AA Employer
<br>
<br>Contracts exceeding $200,000 may be subject to a confidential finance review.</span></em></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table style="width:100%;text-align:center" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>

<td style="text-align:center" valign="top">
<span style="font-size:xx-small">Utah License #95-292934-5501 ~ Arizona License #079839 ~ Nevada License #0034039</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td style="text-align:center" valign="top">
<span style="font-size:xx-small">California License #604354 d.b.a. ROCON COMPANY</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td style="text-align:center" valign="top">
<span style="font-size:xx-small">Washington License #CC01 ROCONC #088RG ~ New Mexico License #031344 ~ Idaho License #10211-AA</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<hr>

<table style="width:100%;text-align:center" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>

<td>
<span style="font-size:xx-small">
<br>PLEASE LOGIN USING THE INFORMATION ABOVE TO ACCEPT/REJECT THE INVITE AND TO DOWNLOAD PLANS</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<h1 style="text-align:center">
<br>
<br></h1></font>
<br><br>Â </div><div style="clear:both"></div><div>To Unsubscribe from receiving invitations, please <a href="https://secure.smartbidnet.com/External/Unsubscribe.aspx?DId=650105303&amp;PId=11151969&amp;CType=1&amp;st=106&amp;e=1" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">Click Here</a>
</div>
Â <div style="clear:both"></div><div>This is an automated email communication so replies to this address will not be answered.</div>

<img src="http://com2.smartbidnet.com/wf/open?upn=Ec818zpKGhsa3nrt3hc9G59m8rgwdlc1vywQ5NYZFh29X36ieqFQbbB1eQ4xPOWO-2FgC4OOD8kd-2B-2FjPJlecZt-2F6M8KmhcoHSqllBh9WbhzHtcM0wkxmIaspKs48mcpqonKaeL-2FjDx2lOs-2FFp6tpGe-2FTMErp1bqHae6GZ3vPk9Qt6zoxRiAMslZiJ1ZtX8ev-2FeBx-2BbWGnB4K5FU0IPE5Rz16Ouuw-2BjY3wGKDr2cchCFa-2BWyuOpUG0ldWPRiFOoc3W2HvIibgrKx1tSQOhzPUYlmMDl-2BfADgOv49bGNy02o-2B11bejm7LLV1tulxKEwIntqlQIz3YExI5xqsuAKxnm4TW4uPfJrlmOT5HTwNWs8NonM-3D" width="1" height="1" border="0" style="height:1px!important;width:1px!important;border-width:0!important;margin-top:0!important;margin-bottom:0!important;margin-right:0!important;margin-left:0!important;padding-top:0!important;padding-bottom:0!important;padding-right:0!important;padding-left:0!important">
</div>`;

const parser = DataParser.create(input);
console.log(parser.parse(['address', 'email', 'logo', 'dueDate', 'companyName']));

// or 

console.log(DataParser.parse(input, ['address', 'email', 'logo', 'dueDate', 'companyName']));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this code.. i can see it is very much helpful to me in getting to achieve my goal.. I will practice the code and let you know how it goes soon.. Thank you once again..